# NSTimer + Modal Problem

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I'm trying to run a timer while running an `NSWindow` as modal, but unfortunately it doesn't work at all. The log is called, the window appears and turns modal, but the timer is never called - why? Am I missing something?

```
    NSLog(@"Checking...");

    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] runModalForWindow:_Window];

    _checkTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(check:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:_checkTimer
                                 forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer: _checkTimer
                                 forMode:NSModalPanelRunLoopMode];
```

Comment: Thanks man for the very good question. It saved my time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing your timer/runloop stuff before starting the modal session.

Answer (score 4):

If you need for some reasons to add timer after starting modal session - so just add timer to run loop mode: NSModalPanelRunLoopMode

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:theTimer
                             forMode:NSModalPanelRunLoopMode];
```

Comment: Thank you for adding this answer. It was exactly what I needed.